# I can not use Form Class of laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to use this.

```
@extends('layouts')

@section('content')
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@method')) }}
        <table>
            <tr><td>Name</td><td>{{ Form::text('name') }}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>email</td><td>{{ Form::text('email') }}</td></tr>
            <tr><th colspan='2'><input type="submit" value='Submit'></th></tr>
        </table>
    {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

But I found It's fail from Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@method'))
I would like to know how to fix this this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What is the problem? Can you show us the error?

Comment: what is the error? do you get the error while outputting the form or submitting it?

Comment: it show "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Answer (score 2):

When developing laravel application, change first the debug configuration:

**app/config/app.php line: 16
'debug' => false to 'debug' => true,**
- this will help you to see the errors, so that it would be easy for us to help you.

And make sure that

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@method')) }}
```

'action' => **'Controller@method'** exists.

Comment: ok. now it show ErrorException Route [userController@add] not defined.

Comment: Yeah, make sure that the controller method is defined in your controller class.

Comment: @RaffyCortez good advice on the debug thing, but you shouldn't be advising people to change the `app/config/app.php`'s debug setting to true, but the `app/config/local/app.php`'s debug setting. Changing the global debug to true will mean that production has debug turned on if the developer forgets to turn it back off. See http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#configuration

Comment: @alexrussell yeah, but the default environment in laravel is production, if i told him to change local/app.php, nothing will happen, I will just suggest that if they add new environment, make sure that 'debug' option in environment app.php config is set correctly. Thanks!

Comment: and since this is not about environment configuration, i didn't make my suggestion about debug option to be complicated, i want to make it simple and easy to understand, however, they will learn how environment configuration works, in the right time.

Answer (score 1):

Should be using

```
@stop()
```

in blade template.

And make sure your method is returning something.  When I build methods I start with a test return value like so

```
return 'hello this works';
```

if the method is called and all is well you'll see that message.

Just use

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return 'this is a test';
});
```

Comment: if use Route::post  
Can i test return value?

Comment: I added some to the answer